# Почему программа не выполняет действие?

Tags: devc++, c++

Нужно перевернуть каждую третью стороку в массиве.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int m, n, **a, i, j, s;
    cout<<"vvedite kol-vo strok "; cin>>m;
    cout<<"vvedite kol-vo stol-v "; cin>>n;
    a = new int *[m];
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        a[i] = new int[n]; 
        }
    for(i = 0; i<m; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<n; j++){
            cout<<"a["<<i+1<<"],["<<j+1<<"] = "; cin>>a[i][j];
            }
        }
    for(i=0;i<m;i++, cout<<"\n"){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++,cout<<"\t"){
            cout<<a[i][j];
            }
        }

   for(i=2; i<m; i=i+3){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            s = a[i][n-1-j];
            a[i][n-1-j] = a[i][j];
            a[i][j] = s;
            }
    }

    cout<<"\nitog :\n";
        for(i=0;i<m;i++, cout<<"\n"){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++,cout<<"\t"){
            cout<<a[i][j];
            }
        }
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Почему она не переворачивается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что переворачивать таким способом нужно только до середины строки.

Comment: Спасибо! Проблема разрешилась, я просто затупил.